# how do you make the header-side-mainlayout

Tags: html, css

I want to know how do you guys make the header-side-main-footer layout in html.

Like this:

```
<html>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="main"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</html>
```

The `div.header` and the `div.footer` have a fixed height. And the `div.content` will hold all the rest height,no scroll bar for the body.

And the `div.side` will have a fixed width,and the `div.main` will hold all the rest width.

The `div.side` can have y-scroll bar.

When the window resize,the `div.content` will expand to fix the height,no scroll bar.

BTW,sometimes the `div.side` and the `div.main` may exchange the position like this:

```
<html>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main"></div>
    <div class="side"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer"></div>
</html>
```

How to you make it?

update:

div.main can not made as overflow:hidden,since it is the container which I use for ceate the map.

```
var map=new google.maps.Map('main',{});
```

Answer (score 0):

Gave `div.side` a height and width and then `overflow:scroll`
Like:

```
div.side{
height:60%;
width: 60%;
overflow: scroll;
}
```

and `div.content` `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

That is how I would do it in html, well I would add a wrapper around it to make centering easy, but that is just me.  I think you want to know about the css, and to be hones, there are going to be many ways one might go about that, the simples being:

```
.header {
    width:whateverpx;
    margin:0 auto;
}
.content {
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
}
.content:after {
    clear:both;
    content:"";
    display:none;
}
.side {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    width: your width for it;
}
.main {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.footer {
    height: whateverpx;
    width: whateverpx;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

and, if you want the content centered add a wrapper around it and add

```
.wrapper {
    width:whatever;
    marging:0 auto;
}
```

or

no wrapper, do this for .content instead

```
.content {
    width: whatever
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: to expand on this a bit, you don't define a whole lot of information... so the widths can be exact px's or they can be percentages.  It totally depends on what YOU want your page to look like, and as such this is a basic setup that can be tweaked to your liking, but we would need a picture of what you want to know.

Comment: Our applicaiton is based on google  map,so something like google  map.